# Making algebraic substitutions with approximations

Tags: replacement, symbolic, approximation

I'm struggling to make a substitution in a symbolic expression where I want to use an approximation. For example if we have the equation
$$\frac{1}{a}\frac{c}{a - b} = \frac{c}{a^{2} - a b} \approx \frac{c}{a^{2}} \quad \text{as} \quad a \gg b $$
How can I do this symbolically with Mathematica. I have tried `Simplify[...]`, with

```
Simplify[(1/a)(c/(a^2 - ab)), a^2 - ab == a^2]
```

which unsurprisingly doesn't work. I also played around with

```
Simplify[(1/a) (c/(a - ab)), a \[GreaterGreater] b]
```

which doesn't seem to change things. I have also tried `Replace`

```
Replace[(1/a) (c/(a - b)), a^2 - a b -> a^2]
```

But again, no joy.

I have always struggle with symbolic substitutions, so if anyone can point to a good question on this site, or an external resource, I'd be much obliged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `Asymptotic`:

```
Asymptotic[ (c/(a^2 - a b)), {b, 0, 1}]
(*c/a^2*)
```

Using `Series` and `Asymptotic`:

```
Asymptotic[Series[c/(a^2 - a*b), {b, 0, 1}], b -> a b]
(*c/a^2*)
```

Answer (score 9):

You could use

```
Series[c/(a^2 - a*b), {a, Infinity, 4}]
```

which yields

[image]

Comment: I should have thought of Series! I'll see if it extends to my exact problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Asymptotic[(1/a) (c/(a^2 - a b)) /. a -> b/eps, eps -> 0]
% /. eps -> b/a (* c/a^3*)
```

Comment: Ulrich Neumann, `Asymptotic[ (c/(a^2 - a b)), {b, 0, 1}]` gives the desired result.

Comment: @E.Chan-López That is quite a useful comment. You might want to consider adding this as an answer.

Comment: @E. Chan-López That's right. But for more complicated approximations, for example with additional condition `c~eps ^u a`, it's useful to introduce `eps`

Comment: You're right, Ulrich Neumann, I noticed. For that reason, I upvoted your answer when I saw that your answer was downvoted.

Comment: @E. Chan-López Thanks for your support!